# Set a PageBreak inside a Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table made of: a title + a hd with the headers of the Table of course and + the cells (that could be a lot).

What I would like to do is how could I do that the Printer recongnizes that if there is no space for entering at least 1 of the Cells of the Table (so in a page it doesnt appears only the title and the headers of it) then ALL the whole table goes to another page.

But, if there is a space for the title+the table headers+1 cell at least that then, it remains on that page and well in the next ones it continus with the other corresponding cells.

Could you help me? Do you know a way (html, css, javascript all welcome! =) )

Thanks in advance,
Orangejuice.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want the `page-break-inside: avoid` CSS3 property with a `print` media query. The doc is here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp

Comment: Thanks Peter! But apparently, it only works with Opera. What about the other browsers? is there a fix or something? Do you know?